# Testing select_tag with Rspec. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to testing page, and I have some problem. The `select` matcher does not work. 
**rspec**

```
  let!(:hotel1) { create(:hotel) }
  let!(:hotel2) { create(:hotel, status: 'rejected') }

it 'with params: status column and existing value' do
      login_admin
      visit admin_hotels_path
      expect(page).to have_content hotel1.title
      expect(page).to have_content hotel2.title
      fill_in :search, with: 'rejected'
      select 'status', from: :search_column
      click_button 'Search'
      expect(page).to have_content hotel2.title
      expect(page).to_not have_content hotel1.title
    end
```

**index**

```
=form_tag admin_hotels_path, method: 'get' do
  =text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
  =select_tag :search_column, options_for_select(Hotel.searchable_columns, params[:search_column])
  =submit_tag 'Search'
```

**controller**

```
  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.search(params[:search], params[:search_column]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
  end
```

The result of testing:

Failures:

```
1) hotels page check the Search with params: status column and existing value
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to_not have_content hotel1.title
       expected #has_content?("Hotel1") to return false, got true
```

But the search from status with this params return one object, because in the factories the status have `approved` value.

**UPDATE**

```
factory :hotel do
    sequence(:title) { |i| "Hotel#{i}" }
    description 'This is a some description for hotel'
    breakfast true
    price 20500
    address { create(:address) }
    user { create(:user) }
    avatar { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/images/example.jpg', "image/jpg") }
    status 'approved'
  end
```

**UPDATE 2.0**

**hotel.rb**

```
  def self.search(keyword, column_name)
    if self.column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
      where("#{column_name} LIKE ?", "#{keyword}")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

  def self.searchable_columns
    wanted_columns = ['title', 'status' ]
    self.column_names.select{ |column| wanted_columns.include?(column) }
  end
end
```

Comment: The title is misleading, this has nothing to do with rspec syntax.

Comment: What's the definition of `Hotel.search`?

Comment: Do not understand the question. 
I have table with all hotel, and I need filtering table from title or status (Hotels have 3 statuses approved, pending, rejected)

Comment: How did you define the search method in Hotel model?

Comment: See update. I add example of hotel model.

Comment: Do you know if the search method is executed twice (one for `visit admin_hotels_path`, another for `click_button 'Search'`)? Also you might have hidden it, I assume sort_column and sort_direction are defined..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59416/discussion-between-bbqbrisket-and-alxgol).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your factory generates hotels with the same name.

Comment: I check values of title and they are different namely `Hotel1 & Hotel2`

Comment: I am not strong in Capybara. Does your Hotel.search work correct? Have you test it via browser?

Comment: I type in textarea `rejected`, choose in the dropdown menu `status` and click `Search` , after all this is given me the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement should be in the format of:

```
select(value, options = {})
```

e.g.,

```
select 'rejected', from: :search_column
```

Ref. [this doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method)

Comment: In the select_tag two options, `title` and `status`. `rejected` type in search textarea.